# Data loss while updating Android application

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am working on app. I am using `SharedPreferences` to store the local data of my app. A `SharedPreference` is used to check whether the user is logged in or not, and proceed accordingly. But when I update the app the user gets logged out and it goes to the login page again.

Comment: Your preference is lost? There might be some other error, preference never get lost after update. It would be better if you show your code

Comment: I think you uninstalled and then installed the app. Shared preferences don't delete in app update.

Comment: Not sure but try after adding `android:allowBackup=true`

Comment: I am updating my app. And check on splash screen if user have data then continue otherwys go to log out page.